# a function in one of my subclasses isn't working even though its the same in the other subclass

Tags: python, pygame

my subclass is having issues with my function "render" even though the other one works just fine, saying
`AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'screen'`
even though my other subclass works just fine along with this it makes me put in my Y co-ordinate twice (once again the function is the same as the other function from the subclass). it doesn't really make much sense

```
 class Predator(Animal):
    def __init__(Self):
        super().__init__()
        Self.Img=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
        Self.PredatorX=0
        Self.PredatorY=0
        Self.screen= screen
        
        
    def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
        Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
        
        



         
class Prey(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(Self):
        super().__init__()
        Self.preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
        Self.preyX=300
        Self.preyY=700
        Self.screen= screen
        
         
    def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
        Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Prey.Render` instead of calling that method on an instance of Prey. See the line immediately above it where you call `predator.Render`, where `predator` is an instance of `Predator`.

Comment: thank you for the help, if you dont mind me asking a follow up question, in the main code there is a function called track, but it doesnt work now so I was wondering what would be the best way to create a function that uses render but also adds the sprites to a sprite group and to a list so I can use that function again

Comment: ah sorry about that

Comment: so when I as another question and some one responds would asking about how it could be implemented and/or if it could be modified a different way a valid question to ask? (sorry I am new and I'm trying to  figure out how this site fully works)

Comment: If the discussion is still about the same problem then that would usually be valid. The line is drawn when a different problem is presented. Essentially, the goal is to ensure that the discussion is relevant to the original question asked.

Comment: ok thank you very much Ill try and not do that again in the future, sorry for any headaches caused